# How to constraint an optional param with another in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following function

```
        private map(model: Model, id?: number, someVariable?:number) {... }
```

My problem is that if `id` exists then `someVariable` must exist. If not, the logic in this method will not work and an exception will arise.

One of the solutions is to set the two variables in a class. However, I am wondering if there is such capability in typescript.

I am using Typescript 2.0.3.

Comment: Why do you don't just throw an exception?
`if (id && !someVariable){ throw exception}`

Comment: ah you already got an exception. What's wrong with that? It's a misuse of that method, so it should raise an exception, imho

Comment: @HerrDerb I'm just asking about more elegant way.

Comment: It's all about how you handle the exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [function overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) for this:

```
map(model: Model);
map(model: Model, id: number, someVariable:number);
map(model: Model, id?: number, someVariable?:number) {
    //implementation
}
```

Then actual implementation signature is not callable:

```
this.map(m); //valid
this.map(m, 1, 2); //valid
this.map(m, 1); //error
```